# Servlet not running on ajax.jquery function

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, servlets, post

Been struggling with this issue, and hoping any can help me figure out what's wrong. The servlet code should be working properly, since it's been tested without jquery/ajax function.

Here's the Jquery.ajax code, and I'm pretty sure it's here it's going wrong. But after hours of changing and trying to configure different settings, it seem that I have come to a halt in amount of options.

What I'm going for is login without refreshing the page.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#submit').click(function() {
                    var dataForm = $('#form1').serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'login',   
                        data: dataForm,         
                        success : function(data) {
                            $('#gg').text(responseText);
                        },
                        error : function() {
                            $('#gg').text(responseText);
                        },
                    });
                });
            });

</script>
```

Servlet:

```
    public class Login extends HttpServlet {

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            resp.setContentType("text/html");  
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();    

            String email = req.getParameter("email");
            String pass = req.getParameter("pass");



        if(Validate.checkUser(email, pass)){

                    out.println("Works");               
            else{       
                out.println("Fail");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the form:

```
<form method="post" id="form1">
     <input type="text" name="email" />         
     <input type="text" name="pass" />
     <input type="button" id="submit" value="login" />
</form>
    <div id="gg"></div>
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.event.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Your function callbacks success nor error is not taking parameter responseText .. see "success : function(data) { .. })" ?

Comment: try `data.responseText`

Comment: I figured it out it seems. You both were correct on the error. Changed it to:
success : function(data) {
     $('#gg').text(data);
    },
    error : function() {
     $('#gg').text(data);
    },